# Interacting with webpage from C++ Application

Tags: javascript, c++, browser

i have a sitation where i want to access HTML DOM object from within my application to update certain parts of web page through javascript commands at run time.

It is a local webpage opened in FireFox which would be accessed by my application, so that the final output is always shown at the webpage which is updated by appliation.

It would be great if you could give me some idea about how this can be accomplished.
I have similar requirement like the webmonkey extension of firefox but need to do it outside of browser from my application.

Comment: It's called “Firefox”, not “FireFox”.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `QtWebKit` from the Qt framework, it provides an OO set of classes to interact with webpages from basic actions to very complicated and advanced stuff. I believe you may find your answer there, a link is provided below...
Good Luck

see [Here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtwebkit.html)